# Is it possible to change the position of generated <tr> by css?

Tags: asp.net, css

Some asp.net controls generate , so to customize its appearance (e.g. childview in grid) i need to change the position of < tr>  content. I don't know any ways to change  position. The only idea is to generate div wrappers by javascript. Does anybody know a better way?

Comment: What do you mean by 'position' of <tr> content? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Do you mean visually, i.e where it is displayed on screen, or structually, i.e. where it is within the HTML source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to "move" the tr to another place, you can try:

```
<table>
<tr id="tr1"><td>test</td><td>test2</td></tr>
<tr id="tr2"><td>test3</td><td>test4</td></tr>
<tr id="tr3"><td>test4</td><td>test5</td></tr>
</body>

<script>
var tr = document.getElementById("tr2");
tr.style.display = 'block';
tr.style.position = 'absolute';
tr.style.top = "100px";
tr.style.left = "100px";
</script>
```

it definitely works in firefox (dont know about ie6-8). If you want to exchange the content with another tr, thats even easier (you just remove/add the tr nodes).